# iFrame content resizing not working on mobile

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, iframe

I've got the following HTML page:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
    #dummy-block {      
        display: block;
        position: relative;
        margin-top: 70px;
        width: 100%;
        height: 70px;
        border: 2px solid red;
    }

    .paragraph {
        display: block;
        position: relative;
        margin-top: 50px;
        width: 100%;
    }
</style>
</head>

<body>

<h1>iFrame Test</h1>
<iframe seamles name="inlineframe" src="About.html" frameborder="1" scrolling="auto" width="100%" height="500px" marginwidth="5" marginheight="5">
</iframe>


<div id="dummy-block">
</div>

<div class="paragraph">
    <h3>Test Paragraph</h3>
    <p>
        Li Europan lingues es membres del sam familie. Lor separat existentie es un myth. Por   
        scientie, musica, sport etc, litot Europa usa li sam vocabular. Li lingues differe solmen in 
        li grammatica, li pronunciation e li plu commun vocabules. Omnicos directe al desirabilite de 
        un nov lingua franca: On refusa continuar payar custosi traductores. At solmen va esser 
        necessi far uniform grammatica, pronunciation e plu sommun paroles. Ma quande lingues 
        coalesce, li grammatica del resultant lingue es plu simplic e regulari quam ti del coalescent 
        lingues. Li nov lingua franca va esser plu simplic e regulari quam li existent Europan 
        lingues. It va esser tam simplic quam Occidental in fact, it va esser Occidental. A un Angleso 
        it va semblar un simplificat Angles, quam un skeptic Cambridge amico dit me que Occidental 
        es.Li Europan lingues es membres del sam familie. Lor separat existentie es un myth. Por 
        scientie, musica, sport etc, litot Europa usa li sam vocabular. Li lingues differe solmen in 
        li grammatica, li pronunciation e li plu commun vocabules. Omnicos directe al desirabilite de 
        un nov lingua franca: On refusa continuar payar custosi traductores. At solmen va esser 
        necessi far uniform grammatica, pronunciation e plu sommun paroles. 
    </p>
</div>



</body>
</html>
```

My "About.html" uses Bootstrap in order to achieve responsiveness, this responsiveness works in the iframe if the page is accessed through my desktop's browser, I can resize the window and the content of the iframe will be resized as well, meaning that if I resize the window to 400px or something similar the frame will appear in 'mobile mode'.

But once I uploaded the code to my server and checked it out from my phone, the iframe was not being resized, it's displaying the 'desktop version' of my site.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I figured it out! As long as the page that contains the iframe has:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=0">
```

the iframe will be automatically resized when required.

Well, at least that was what worked for me in this case.

Comment: how do you do it for tablet view?